# Android send object to c# web service with headers

Tags: c#, android, http-headers, http-post, http-get

I have a web service that receive a SoapHeader class object, the code of web service is below

```
public class MyHeader : SoapHeader
{
     public DateTime Created;
     public string Username{get; set;}
     public long Expires { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[SoapHeader("myHeaderMemberVariable")]
public void MyWebMethod()
{
     // Process the SoapHeader.
     if (myHeaderMemberVariable.Username.Equals("admin"))
     {
          // Do something interesting.
     }
}
```

I need to call this web service from my android app, i use the code below:

```
String body ="admin";
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8");
stringEntity.setChunked(true);

// Request parameters and other properties.
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.2.2.184/service/servicedata.asmx?MyWebMethod");
httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
httpPost.addHeader("myHeaderMemberVariable", soapAction);

// Execute and get the response.
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = null;

response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

String strResponse = null;
if (entity != null) {
        strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the problem is that I cannot specify the fields of objects when use HttpGet.setHeader because it receives string values. So how can i specify the value of 'Username' and 'Expires' of the SoapHeader object from my android code.

Comment: `because it receives string values.` ??? Please elaborate. And show what you tried already?

Comment: `httpPost.addHeader("myHeaderMemberVariable", soapAction);` here i send a string value to SoapHeader, the question shows how i tried already, thank you

Comment: We see nothing. We see no user name or something with expires in it. So how could we check it? Or know what you tried?

Comment: I dont send any username or something what is send is `httpPost.addHeader("myHeaderMemberVariable", soapAction);` where `myHeaderMemberVariable` is the SoapHeader name and the web service returns `Object reference not set to an instance of object`. What is my fault in the code? do i need to send an object or what?

Comment: Well you can read the eror message. Its clear. But how to do it is something else. But you should inc!ude username and expires. Show what you tried already. Show your soapAction. How you build it.

Comment: How can i send 'Username' and 'Expires' ??